# Limpiar comentarios en una cadena HTML con PHP

Tags: php, html

Tengo una cadena html y necesito eliminar el código comentado en esa cadena es decir si encuentro:

```
"código útil <!-- codigo basura --> mas código útil <!-- mas código basura -->
```

Eliminar todo lo que es basura

```
for($cadenaHTML){ 
   if(<!--){
      borrar hasta (-->)
   } 
}
```

básicamente es la idea o algo similar

Comment: No entiendo. Primeramente, los comentarios no son necesariamente *código basura*... podrías ser denunciado por la *ACC*, Asociación de Comentaristas de Código :) y segundo, no se entiende bien lo que quieres hacer. Podrías copiar tu código en un editor cualquiera que maneje expresiones regulares y decirle que te elimine todo lo que está entre los delimitadores por ejemplo. Le falta información a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si bien sería sencillo eliminar los comentarios HTML con una expresión regular como:

```
$cadenaHTML = preg_replace( '/<!--(?!\[)[^-]*(?:-(?!->)[^-]*)*-->/', '', $cadenaHTML);
```

- > <sup>Si se preguntan, `[^-]*(?:-(?!->)[^-]*)*` es mucho más eficiente que usar `.*?`. Ver [*Unrolling the loop*](http://flylib.com/books/en/2.482.1.45/1/).</sup>

hay algunos escenarios en los que fallaría. Por ejemplo con `<--` dentro del value de un input.

---

Es muy sencillo procesar HTML con **[DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)**, son las herramientas que están pensadas para eso.

Simplemente se genera el DOM así:

```php
//Englobamos en body porque tu ejemplo no tiene
//para corregirlo y que lo procese bien
$html = '<body>' . $cadenaHTML . '</body>';

//Generar el DOM
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_NONET | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

Y buscamos los comentarios con XPATH

```php
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//comment()') as $comment) {
    // ...
}
```

Para ir eliminando uno por uno:

```php
$comment->parentNode->removeChild($comment);
```

Y guardamos el resultado como string:

```php
$resultado = $dom->saveHTML();
```

**Código:**

```php
<?php
//Limpiar comentarios en una cadena HTML con PHP
// https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114030/127

$cadenaHTML = "codigo <b>util</b> <!-- codigo basura --> mas codigo util <!-- mas codigo basura -->";

//Englobamos en body porque tu ejemplo no tiene
//para corregirlo y que lo procese bien
$html = '<body>' . $cadenaHTML . '</body>';

//Generar el DOM
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_NONET | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

//Buscar cada comentario
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//comment()') as $comment) {
    //eliminarlo
    $comment->parentNode->removeChild($comment);
}

//Guardar el html
$resultado = $dom->saveHTML();

//Imprimir el resultado (escapando caracteres especiales! para verlo como texto)
echo htmlentities($resultado);
```

Resultado:

```php
<body>codigo <b>util</b>  mas codigo util </body>
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/m31Ue